# PHP operator '->' $foo-> {''}

Tags: php, operator-keyword

I noticed that on php with the JSON lib we can access an element with a syntax I haven't seen before.

```
$jsonObject->{'myvar'}; // return the value of myvar on the jsonobject
```

What this statement mean?

Comment: as far as I know it works with every single `stdclass object` property or, more simply, any `object` property. Usually, you are about to use such a syntax when you have spaces in the variable names or something like that, like: `$object->{"hello world"};`

Comment: what information are you looking for with "how is this implemented?" do you want to understand the code that drives it, or do you want documentation on that particular feature?

Comment: Often json indexes can have spaces so the use of `{}` allows you to access the data otherwise `$object->my index` won't work but `$object->{'my index'}` will work

Comment: @zzzzBov Actually yes, i wanted to understand that piece of code.

Well, now i understant thanks all.

Comment: @S.Blaise, which piece of code? The code in your question or the *implementation* of the arrow operator in the PHP language? "How is this implemented?" implies the later, while your statement implies the former.

Comment: @zzzzBov my piece of code, I don't know why but i tought that was specially implemented by the lib, sort of operator overloading. So i asked how it was implemented. i'll edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think it is inherent with the JSON lib.

It's just another way to determine the name of the variable you want to call. For example, it's useful when you want to decide dynamically which variable should be called, something that is of great use in magic methods.

`$var->{"var_name"}` is the equivalent of `$var->var_name`.

You can do things like these as well:

```php
$key = "key_name";

var_dump($object->{$key});
```

You can also access keys with *invalid* characters such as dots or commas.

```php
$key = "key.name.nice";

var_dump($object->{$key});
```

Comment: +1 but I think it's worth to point out that it's particularly useful when you need to access properties that have "invalid" characters like blank spaces. Just saying.